# Evidence that electrons don't exist between orbitals?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons

I don't understand the logical jump that was made early on in the atomic age, to conclude that electrons jump in and out of existence when moving between orbitals? Similarly, why do electrons need to occupy everywhere in the orbital at once with a probability, rather than simply moving around it quickly? This is a problem I have with the overall logic of  quantum interpetations of physics and the uncertainty principle.

For instance, if in the smallest amount of time we could measure, an electron travelled around its orbit, say, 400 million times, and it took 1/800 millionth of that time to pass between orbitals, obviously we would be unable to observe it. But that doesn't mean it isn't happening.
Even the uncertainty principle seems to me to apply similarly to our scale of the world as to electrons: if I am walking, you can't technically measure my position and my path or speed at the same time, only one or the other. That doesn't mean I don't exist when you don't know my location, it just means you don't know where I am currently existing. I don't see why this has to be different for subatomic particles? For instance, why can't it just be a particle moving along a wave path, why does it need to be a particle and a wave at the same time? I don't see where this logic came from or what supports it. For instance, in a double-slit experiment, what logic  excludes the possibility of a particle that is simply moving in a wave-like path? If only one particle passes through only one slit, it doesn't cause an interference pattern, not because it was detected and therefore ceased to be a wave, but simply that there was not another particle to cause interference. Particles travelling in a wave-path might of course be expected to travel through either one or the other slit, but surely each individual particle only goes through one slit?

I have a similar problem with describing orbitals as probability clouds. A probability isn't something real, it is merely the quantification of an expectation based in some data. For instance, a coin being flipped may be expected to have approximately 0.5 probability of landing on heads. But it either happens or it doesn't, it doesn't 0.5 happen. So the probability was never a real event, just an expectation. So why can't an electron be physically travelling around its orbital really fast? Of course there will be a higher probability of it being in a particularly well-teavelled part of the orbital at any one time, but in reality it isn't everywhere, it is just in one place, or indeed travelling along it's path, but at a scale of time so many times faster than we can measure that it seems to be everywhere at once. But it, in fact, isn't. Can anyone explain to me why the less sensible logic is widely accepted, but the more intuitive explanation doesn't fit the data?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not certain whether "is quantum mechanics correct?" is a relevant question for Chemistry.SE. I guess it might be ok, but Physics would definitely have been better. One obvious objection to "things moving very fast" is that there's a [speed cap on things moving quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light). [Of course, we could *then* move on to asking what evidence there is for relativity, but well...] Another objection is [Bell's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem).

Comment: Note, also, that when writing Markdown you need to enter two line breaks to create a new paragraph.

Comment: Evidence that something does not exist is not possible. There is possible evidence (or lack of it) that something exists. // Like the famous request for proof of the unicorn non-existence.

Comment: You're hardly the first or last person who thinks quantum mechanics is counter-intuitive. But with a century of experimentation covering ins and outs which not many can even conceive, Nature operates to an *incredible* precision as if it were quantum-mechanical, so you might as well say that it **is**. Rather than trying to seek flaws with pure argumentation, you should find the humility to fix your intuition and definitions (which may require throwing them in the bin entirely and rebuilding from scratch) and spend the effort to understand some of the actual mathematical framework.

Comment: There is no between. The very notion is simply missing; the electrons can't be there, much like they can't be blue, or stubborn, or upside down.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Your question clearly shows an effort to put your own reasoning into words, and probably represents a line of thought that a number of students of chemistry struggle with. There are many subquestions in your post, which makes it somewhat difficult to provide a single answer, however. I'd recommend reading about the history of quantum mechanics to dig deeper.

Comment: "you can't technically measure my position and my path or speed at the same time, only one or the other." Yes I can! I measure your speed continuously via  the Doppler effect of light reflected at your surface while you pass through a light switch.

Comment: I'm upvoting, not because this is an advanced question on a controversial matter (it is not), but because it is an important question that nearly every student who encounters quantum mechanics will grapple with.

Answer (score 2):

Many scientists over the past century have struggled and continue to struggle with the representation of events at the atomic scale, as exemplified by the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics) on *interpretations of quantum mechanics* or recent [headlines](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/07/opinion/sunday/quantum-physics.html) like "even physicists don't understand quantum mechanics". Schrödinger himself is known to have been disillusioned with the interpretations others ascribed to his wavefunction. So the questions above are not easily answered.

We can, however, point out a fundamental issue with any whizzing particle model: *accelerated* charges should radiate out energy according to the Larmor [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) as observed in particle accelerators.

If you conceive of the electron as a point-like particle with a defined trajectory over time, then logically you should also be able to define its speed and acceleration. Any nonzero acceleration should lead to an emission of radiation and hence an energy loss over time, with the electron inevitably crashing into the nucleus within a fraction of a second. This clearly does not describe atoms as we know them.

It is the inability to fit atomic observations like non-radiation into purely classical models that led to the development and adoption of the abstract description of the atom in quantum mechanics. Not very intuitive, but we'll have to put up with it until something better comes along...

Comment: *Any nonzero acceleration should lead to an emission of radiation* 
This is only partially true, as constant linear acceleration does not lead to radiation what is used in linear accelerators. As this radiation is proportional to the time derivative of acceleration, which is zero for constant acceleration vector.

Comment: P.S.: I have thought the same in past, but was corrected by physicists it is not about proportionality to (x'')^2, but about x' . x'''.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - proportionality to x'' is in indeed the widely reported condition, but I know there are a few subtleties involved as highlighted in e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonradiation_condition or 
https://skullsinthestars.com/2008/04/19/invisibility-physics-acceleration-without-radiation-part-i/. If you have any reference to the x''' dependency, I'd be interested.